# Eclipse: Instant autocompletion

Tags: java, eclipse, intellij-idea

I am not entirely comfortable with way how **Eclipse** autocompletes code. I like the way how **IntelliJ** prompts suggestions (some say it's rather aggresive, but I like it that way).

So I went to: Window -> Preferences -> Java -> Editor -> Content Assist and set delay to 0ms and autoactivation trigger to *ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz*.

Now Eclipse looks really fast with autocompletion but there's one very annoying thing:
It completes proposed names of variables **on every space hit**.

So when I want to type:

```
String joe = "Joe";
```

eclipse is fast enough to ruin it to:

```
String joeString = ...;
```

In other words , pressing: `String joe[space]`makes`joeString.` I hope I was clear enoguh, thanks for suggestions :)

Comment: One of the most annoying issues I've ever seen in an IDE.

Comment: Agreed,very-very annoying behaviour. And not only with space, Eclipse does it with the semicolon too, so if you say: String joe; Eclipse "corrects" it to: String joeString; It's a pity there's no solution to this.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Stop spacebar keypress from triggering autocomplete in Eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14297735/stop-spacebar-keypress-from-triggering-autocomplete-in-eclipse)

Answer (score 8):

You can uncheck 'Window -> Preferences -> Java -> Editor -> Content Assist -> Insert single proposals automatically'. Once done, you should only get a popup window with the proposal but it will not be inserted automatically in the editor.

Comment: This doesn't work for me. You can try that with joeString example.

Comment: Ok, you have to press 'Esc' to make the proposal popup go away. Pressing  'Space' just selects the first proposal and I do not see a way out of it (selection with space works nicely when content assist is not autoactivated everywhere and I do not think we are going to change that)

Comment: Yep I realized I have to press Esc but that's too annoying to get used to :/

Comment: agree, the problem is that the auto-activation everywhere is kind of a hack/trick and things are not really designed for this. You can open a bug against JDT UI (https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/enter_bug.cgi?product=JDT), and describe the problem you are facing.

Comment: This doesn't fix the issue. In fact it appears to not do anything at all. One has to wonder: What DOES that option even do?

Answer (score 4):

Increase the delay so that you can still type short things without stopping. I'm not sure there is another way to solve it as you are asking Eclipse to always instantaneously autocomplete, and space chooses it's current autocomplete guess.

Comment: Sorry, but this is not what I am looking for.

Comment: I don't see why users have to dumb down their productivity just to workaround an egregious oversight by Eclipse developers. Why not have the best of both worlds? Instant pop-up, and don't force-insert unless we press enter. I'm no coding master but surely this must be a laughably easy task?????

Answer (score 0):

There is a solution [on the issue tracker](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=348857#attach_236956) for this. 
Copy the [jar](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/attachment.cgi?id=236956) in the eclipse/dropins folder. With the next restart space is diabled as autocompletion trigger.

Comment: This disables _all_ auto-completion triggers. That is obviously not what the OP asked for.

Comment: For me only the space-key is disabled as autocompletion trigger